# Objdump not showing complete address

Tags: linux, objdump

Is there a way to get the full address in objdump?
Command being used is: `objdump -d progname`

[image]

The leading zeros are the incorrect.  The addresses should be as follows:

[image]

The last three values in the address are correct; but, I'd much like the full address to be shown in objdump.

Comment: Do these addresses start from *zero*?

Comment: No, when I run it in edb the addresses are shown as the second image.

Comment: I guess my first question would be, are you looking for a physical or virtual address? Second, assuming this is a user space application, I don't think `objdump` knows where the kernel will place the application at run time, and even less likely that it would know the physical address.

Comment: It would be useful to know how `objdump` is being called from the command-line.

Comment: Yes it would.  `objdump -d progname`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before your application gets loaded, you cannot tell where it will end in the memory.

Try the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    printf("%p\n", main);
}
```

Compile it with `gcc test.c` and run several times.

My results show:

```
0x55f71f8936b0
0x5630ed7ff6b0
0x558a18eea6b0
...
```

So you can't know for sure where it will end in the memory. I believe it was not always the case, and this behaviour is intended as a security "thingy". I wouldn't be surprised if older kernel/loaders gave the same address on each run. I do not know that for sure, though.

Of course `objdump` will give you relative addresses:

```
00000000000006b0 <main>:
```

Keep in mind that the output of this program does not give you physical addresses, they are still virtual.

The point is that addresses dumped by `objdump` are a responsibility of the **linker** and actual virtual addresses from each execution are there because of the **loader**.

Comment: Ok, that makes a lot of since.  I was working on an older kernel and recently made the change to a newer one.  Just didn't realize that there was that nifty security feature.  I looked for a while before I caved in and asked.  Guess I was searching for the wrong thing.  Anyways, thanks for the info.

Comment: Please keep in mind that whichever loader you use, the final address of the symbol will not be available to objdump. With the older loader this runtime addresses could be the same on each run, but that's the only difference, I guess.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the accepted answer:

To get the right addresses, you run the program in gdb, then type start, then do "disas functionname" and it shows the right addresses now.